# How to refer different configuration files with on fixed name for different different environments

Tags: python-3.x

How do you manage different configuration files for different environments with single file name.

We've come up with some options, File are organized like

```
config.prod.ini
config.test.ini
config.dev.ini
```

And on each environment we create a symlink that points to the correct file.

```
Example: 
config.ini -> config.prod.ini (on production environment)
config.ini -> config.test.ini (on test environment)
config.ini -> config.dev.ini (on development environment)
```

The .py files reads only from config.ini.
Our systems are written in python 3.x
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Use an environment variable which contains the config file you want to use,
Otherwise you can pass it as a command line argument

Setting the environment variables is dependent on the OS (or hosting service) you are using.
You can access those variables from python using `os` module `os.environ` is a dictionary maps all the environment variables of the current process to their values

Also, you can use the [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) module to load environment variables from a file in your project. this allows you to set a unique configuration for each environment running your code

Comment: Yes, i was passing like that only, I think we should avoid making distinction between test and production inside the code. 
We could just to refer to a fixed file name like "gerrit.ini". And on the test environment we make sure the gerrit.test.ini file will be renamed to gerrit.ini.

Comment: What I meant is, that you can have in your code all the config files of all the environments, and inside the Testing environment define an environment variable like `MY_PROJECT_CONFIG_FILE=/app/config-files/config.test.ini`
So the code remains the same in all environments but use a different config file on each one